# Microsoft Graph Delta API for querying /devicemanagement/manageddevices?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, intune, microsoft-graph-intune, device-management, graph-query

I'm trying to sync the devices from Microsoft Endpoint manager https://endpoint.microsoft.com . After performing a full read once, I would like to query the changes alone on daily basis. We are able to fetch all devices using https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/devicemanagement/manageddevices but we couldn't find any delta API for managed devices.

Is there any way to query the changes in managed devices from Microsoft Intune via graph API ?

Answer (score 0):

Managed devices are not listed in [supported resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview#supported-resources) for delta query, so tracking changes for managed devices is not supported.